Service Worker cannot cache large videos
I am trying to implement a caching mechanism for a website with pwa functionality. My goal is to cache every page and its content that has been loaded. This works fine f.e. in Google Chrome (127.0.6533.100) and Microsoft Edge (127.0.2651.98) on Windows. In production, the website runs on a Raspberry Pi 4 (Debian 12.6) on Chromium (126.0.6478.164). Thats were the caching mechanism doesn't work as expected. All pages and content are correctly cached, exept large videos. The videos are of "large" file size (at around 50mb). On pages with videos, I receive the following console error:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Cache.put() encountered a network error.

Does someone know how I can cache the videos successfully on chromium?
const cacheName = 'cache-v1';
const fallbackCacheName = 'cache-fallback';
const offlinePage = '/offline.html';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
console.log('Service worker install event!');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
console.log('Service worker activate event!');
event.waitUntil(
caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
return Promise.all(
cacheNames.map((name) => {
if (name !== cacheName && name !== fallbackCacheName) {
return caches.delete(name);
}
})
);
})
);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
const url = new URL(event.request.url);

if (url.origin === location.origin && !url.pathname.includes('typo3/')) {
console.log('Fetch intercepted for:', event.request.url);

// Check if the requ
// est has a Range header
if (event.request.headers.get('Range')) {
// Create a new request without the Range header
const newRequest = new Request(event.request.url, {
method: event.request.method,
headers: new Headers(event.request.headers),
mode: event.request.mode,
credentials: event.request.credentials,
cache: 'no-store'
});

// Remove the Range header
newRequest.headers.delete('Range');

event.respondWith(
caches.match(newRequest).then((cachedResponse) => {
if (cachedResponse) {
return cachedResponse;
}

return fetch(newRequest).then((networkResponse) => {
if (networkResponse.status === 200) {
const clonedResponse = networkResponse.clone();
return caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
cache.put(newRequest, clonedResponse);
return networkResponse;
});
}

return networkResponse;
}).catch((error) => {
console.error('Fetch failed:', error);
return caches.match(offlinePage);
});
})
);
} else {
// Handle requests without a Range header
event.respondWith(
caches.match(event.request).then((cachedResponse) => {
if (cachedResponse) {
return cachedResponse;
}

return fetch(event.request, { cache: 'no-store' }).then((networkResponse) => {
return caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
return networkResponse;
});
}).catch((error) => {
console.error('Fetch failed:', error);
return caches.match(offlinePage);
});
})
);
}
}
});

What I tried:

I tried different caching mechanism's in service worker (plain js and workbox) --> all worked in modern browers but not chromium
Since the videos are loded by 206 response (partial content), I tried to make a separate call for caching the video in one piece
I tried caching the large videos statically  --> worked in modern browers but not chromium

